# Making a Custom Post Type Plugin - keep getting the white screen of death

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, fatal-error

I'm very new to WordPress Development and I'm attempting to make a custom post type business directory style plugin in my plugins folder for my site, but everytime I activate it I get the white screen of death over my entire web site. I've definitely tracked it down to this plugin but I can't see what I've done that's causing it.

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Special Coffee CPT
    Plugin URI: http://danijoypractice.x10host.com
    Description: This plugin creates a custom post type & template page
    Author: Danielle Rautiainen
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: http://danijoypractice.x10host.com
*/

add_action('init', 'local_business_directory_register'); 

function local_business_directory_register() { 

$args = array( 
  'label' => __('Business Directory'), 
  'singular_label' => __('Business'), 
  'public' => true, 
  'taxonomies' => array('category'),
  'show_ui' => true, 
  'capability_type' => 'post', 
  'hierarchical' => true, 
  'has_archive' => true,
  'supports' => array('title', 'editor', ),
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'businesses', 'with_front' => false),
  ); 
}


  register_post_type( 'businesses' , $args );
  register_taxonomy("business-type", array("businesses"), array(
  "hierarchical" => true,
  "label" => "Business Type",
  "singular_label" => "Business Type",
  "rewrite" => true
     )
    );

add_action("admin_init", "local_business_directory_meta");

function local_business_directory_meta ()
{
 add_meta_box("business-meta", "Business Options",     "local_business_directory_options", "businesses", "normal", "high");
} 

function local_business_directory_options()
{ 
 global $post; 
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID); 
$address = $custom["address"][0];
$website = $custom["website"][0]; 
$phone = $custom["phone"][0]; 
?> 
 <style type="text/css">
 <?php include('business-directory.css'); ?>
 </style>

 <div class="business_directory_extras">
 <?php $website= ($website == "") ? "http://" : $website; ?>
  <div>
   <label>Website:</label>
   <input name="website" value="<?php echo $website; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div>
   <label>Phone:</label>
   <input name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" />
  </div>
  <div>
  <label>Address:</label>
   <textarea name="address"><?php echo $address; ?>" /></textarea>
  </div>
 </div> 
 <?php 
} 
add_action('save_post', 'local_business_directory_save_extras'); 
function business_manager_save_extras(){  
global $post;  
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){

   return $post_id;
   }else{
     update_post_meta($post->ID, "website", $_POST["website"]); 
     update_post_meta($post->ID, "address", $_POST["address"]);
     update_post_meta($post->ID, "phone", $_POST["phone"]);
   } 
  }  

?>
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Turn on the PHP Debugging, so you can see PHP errors. There could be anything from missing semicolon to not closing parenthesis properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your function right after the $args array. You need to enclose properly

```
function local_business_directory_register() { 

$args = array( 
  'label' => __('Business Directory'), 
  'singular_label' => __('Business'), 
  'public' => true, 
  'taxonomies' => array('category'),
  'show_ui' => true, 
  'capability_type' => 'post', 
  'hierarchical' => true, 
  'has_archive' => true,
  'supports' => array('title', 'editor', ),
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'businesses', 'with_front' => false),
  ); 

  register_post_type( 'businesses' , $args );
  register_taxonomy("business-type", array("businesses"), array(
  "hierarchical" => true,
  "label" => "Business Type",
  "singular_label" => "Business Type",
  "rewrite" => true
     )
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code.

**NOTE: You should debug your errors using your error logs. :|**

First of all, you added `register_post_type( 'businesses' , $args );` after the closing brace of your `local_business_directory_register()` function.

Secondly you're referencing `$post_id` in two different places without the variable being set. Since you define `global $post`, you can reference the **post ID** using `$post->ID`

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Special Coffee CPT
    Plugin URI: http://danijoypractice.x10host.com
    Description: This plugin creates a custom post type & template page
    Author: Danielle Rautiainen
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: http://danijoypractice.x10host.com
*/

add_action('init', 'local_business_directory_register');

function local_business_directory_register() {

    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Business Directory'),
        'singular_label' => __('Business'),
        'public' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('category'),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', ),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'businesses', 'with_front' => false),
    );
    register_post_type( 'businesses' , $args );
}


register_taxonomy("business-type", array("businesses"), array(
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "label" => "Business Type",
        "singular_label" => "Business Type",
        "rewrite" => true
    )
);

add_action("admin_init", "local_business_directory_meta");

function local_business_directory_meta ()
{
    add_meta_box("business-meta", "Business Options",     "local_business_directory_options", "businesses", "normal", "high");
}

function local_business_directory_options()
{
    global $post;
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post->ID;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $address = $custom["address"][0];
    $website = $custom["website"][0];
    $phone = $custom["phone"][0];
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        <?php include('business-directory.css'); ?>
    </style>

    <div class="business_directory_extras">
        <?php $website= ($website == "") ? "http://" : $website; ?>
        <div>
            <label>Website:</label>
            <input name="website" value="<?php echo $website; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Phone:</label>
            <input name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Address:</label>
            <textarea name="address"><?php echo $address; ?>" /></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('save_post', 'local_business_directory_save_extras');
function business_manager_save_extras(){
    global $post;
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){

        return $post->ID;
    }else{
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "website", $_POST["website"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "address", $_POST["address"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "phone", $_POST["phone"]);
    }
}

?>
```